# Using Razor Inside of Javascript to Alter AngularJS "$http.post" URL

Tags: angularjs, razor

I'm using C# ASP.NET, and have built some web APIs, cshtml and Javascript files with AngularJS.

Specifically in the Javascript files, there are AngularJS $http.post() methods that are working great, however, the problem comes in when I publish the ASP.NET website to a web server in IIS that has the following URL: https://website.com/Staging/xxx - the http post methods are trying to reach https://website.com/API/xxx instead of https://website.com/Staging/API/xxx - how can I overcome this?

I've tried sneaking some Razor syntax into the Javascript files but Visual Studio IDE will just not accept it. Here is my $http.post method:

```
$http.post('../api/RefreshLevel/', parameters ).then(function(response)
```

How can I alter this url in a way that it'll be able to access the API regardless of whether the home directory of the IIS application is running in https://website.com/ or https://website.com/Staging

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not seeing any Razor syntax in the JavaScript there, but if you add Razor to JavaScript files, then you have to pass those files through the Razor engine, which normally does not happen (for good reason). I would suggest either adding a `data-` attribute to your `html` or `body` element which you can get after the page is loaded, or add an API method that returns that information that you can call when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your AngularJS app's route is something like this: https://website.com/Staging/#!/your-angularjs-routing.

You can use:

```
var path = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname
```

OR

```
var path = window.location.href.split("#")[0]
```

the variable "path" will have "https://website.com/Staging/". Now you can do

```
$http.post(path + 'api/RefreshLevel/', parameters ).then(function(response)
```

which will give you https://website.com/Staging/api/RefreshLevel/